# Automatically Login to Zoho Applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-sign-on, zoho

I had previously created a script that automatically logs users into Zoho reports when they click on a link.  Essentially, it enables single sign on through a shared user ID to access Zoho Reports.

This script has worked for a long time, but no longer does the trick.

Here is the old script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({  
        type:"GET",        
        url: "https://accounts.zoho.com/login",  // Send the login info to this page
        data: { LOGIN_ID: "username", PASSWORD: "password", IS_AJAX: "true", remember :-1,  servicename: "ZohoReports"}, 
        dataType: "jsonp", 
        timeout: 200000,
        complete: function() { location.href="https://reports.zoho.com";}      
    });
    });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried several modifications to the script, but I have not had any luck.
If anyone has some ideas, I'd be happy to hear them.

Comment: is there supposed to be a space after the param `remember :` ?

Comment: @gibberish it wouldn't make a difference

Comment: I they just changed their login form.  I have watched the http traffic during a manual login and the same values are being passed by POST.  Of course, I can only do a GET via cross-domain JSON call.  Maybe they just do not accept a GET any longer.  The did add another parm getticket: false.  I have tried including that, but it does not do the trick.

Comment: @Bidwell 5 years later but... did you find any workaround? I'm trying to do the same now without success.

Comment: I was not able to find a workaround.  They are using a key in their cookie, that needs to be sent back to them with credentials.  I could do this on a server, but not through a web browser remote session like I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one login for all users? I guess there is a limit on number of concurrent logins you can use. Check with Zoho Accounts support.

Comment: It seems to allow me to login with the same ID manually within separate browsers and computers.  That may turn out to be a problem, but it doe not look like it is related to this issue.